# MongoDB aggregate sorting different response on same values

Tags: database, mongodb, sorting, aggregate

when i was pagination with mongodb aggregation, i found a problem. I'll detail this a little bit. This problem only happens when sorting. I made a pattern to keep it simple.
Model have a count (number) random generated for sorting and have id (number) for so that we can do it visually and it is unique.

Aggregate pipeline like

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{
        $sort:{
              count:-1
           }
        },
        {
            $skip : 0
        },
        {
            $limit :2
        }])
```

Example limit 2
Returned data

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6027005ffba493078dca3580"),
    "count" : 9,
    "id" : 38
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6027005ffba493078dca3565"),
    "count" : 9,
    "id" : 11
}
```

When limit example 3
Returned data

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6027005ffba493078dca3587"),
    "count" : 9,
    "id" : 45
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6027005ffba493078dca3580"),
    "count" : 9,
    "id" : 38
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6027005ffba493078dca3565"),
    "count" : 9,
    "id" : 11
}
```

For limit 2 first element id = 38,
For limit 3 first element id = 45

And its returned always different response for different limit skip value, for same value sorting.
This problem is preventing me from pagination properly.

If I add a second sorting example

```
$sort:{
         count:-1
         _id: 1
      }
}
```

Its a resolved.

What is the reason? and another solution?

Comment: By default mongo output values in the order that are found so there is no "default sort" or another way to do that, only sort by desired values.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior when document with id:45 is inserted immediately after the limit:2 aggregation example was executed , the limit:3 example will show you the document with id:45 on the top place since the documents/indexes are loaded for sorting  based on the natural insertion order by document _id and the _id is monotonically increasing already sorted.
Based on the above I don't think it make any difference if you add also the _id in the sort stage since documents will be automatically sorted based on the _id if it is not specified and the count value is same for all documents  ...

Comment: id 45 don't inserted after aggregation. It inserted before aggregation. I agree with some of your answers. But When i add _id in sorting  there is no problem. And like a said different limit value returns different sorting.

Comment: Did some testing in v.4.4 and I dont see such a randomness in the behaviour unless there is some other stages in the aggregation before the $sort and the natural documents order is not preserved , what is the mongod version you use?

Comment: mongo version 4.2.3 you can create example 1k dumy data, count number between 1-10 and try again.